# Pandas AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'down'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, attributeerror

I am using the below code and the output is exactly what I expect. I am trying to create a new df from the below code so i can remove rows and join it to a third df.

```
df4 = plays.groupby(['posteam','down']).size()
df4 = pd.DataFrame(df4)
display(df4)
```

But when I run this code in the next cell it is returning the above error.

```
df4 = df4[[df4.down != '3.0']]
```

i am trying to remove all instances of '3.0' in the "down" column of the df.

i am trying to remove all instances of '3.0' in the "down" column of the df.

Comment: `df4 = plays.groupby(['posteam','down']).size().reset_index(name='count')`

Comment: You probably want `plays.groupby(['posteam','down'], as_index=False).size()`

Comment: We need sample data to be able to give a definitive answer.